# What's the design decision for differentiating leading and trailing trivia in Roslyn

Tags: c#, typescript, roslyn

In Roslyn, each syntax token has associated leading and trailing trivia with it. What was the decision of adding *both* leading and trailing trivia, instead of, say, sole leading trivia and an EOF empty token?

Does the presence of both provide some advantages over a single type of trivia?

A brief google search told me that first roslyn got published in 2011 while first Typescript was published in 2012. Before Roslyn, there was no concept of "trivia", so I assume TS based some of it's work on Roslyn. [This comment on TS official github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1678#issuecomment-70150126) confirms, that in TS there is only leading trivia.

Based on that I reached a conclusion that the original distinction between leading and trailing trivia in Roslyn could have been a mistake, and TS addressed it. Is that correct?

My gut tells me that the model that TS adopted is easier to maintain (for example no edge cases when working with both previous token's trailing trivia next token's leading trivia).

Comment: Why don't you ask this question in the same place you found the comment?

Comment: Preserve source fidelity.

Comment: @IanKemp issue is locked, asking in new issue? SO is a good place for those kinds of questions. 
PauloMorgado, fidelity shouldn't be any worse with leading trivia only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for having both was to make writing refactorings easier. For example, consider you have a refactoring that is "remove unused local"; how do you want to deal with comments? In this case:

```
// This boolean stores whether we have connected
bool connected;
int bytesReceived;
```

The user probably expects the comment to be logically applied to the boolean, and so it'd count as leading trivia. And in this case:

```
bool connected;     // This boolean stores whether we have connected
int bytesReceived;
```

It's now trailing trivia, but still attached to the local variable you probably logically think of it being attached to.

Now, there's plenty of cases where the heuristic doesn't work, and the decision was to keep the parser's logic consistent rather than adding a bunch of special cases. In the end, we did have to create a bunch of helper methods in the IDE to deal with those cases. Our team motto eventually became "trivia isn't trivial".